# MaraiDB / MySQL Insert Into Table From Select Query But On Duplicate Key Use Data From Select Query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, on-duplicate-key

I have created table A as follows:

[image]

I put in the data above using a simple **INSERT INTO** and **SELECT** statement. Now that the source data is corrected, I want to used the **INSERT INTO, SELECT, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**, but when I run the code, the *0's* and *NULL* that you see above does not update to the new value.

Here is my code

```
INSERT INTO
TABLEA (uniqueid, year, month, costcentre, amount)

SELECT
  SS.uniquekey, SS.year, SS.month, SS.source, SS.totalamount
FROM
 (SELECT
    uniquekey, `YEAR`, `MONTH`, SOURCE, totalamount
  FROM
    TABLEB
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    uniquekey, `YEAR`, `MONTH`, SOURCE, totalamount
  FROM
    TABLEC
 ) as SS
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE
  TABLEA.YEAR = VALUES(SS.year),
  TABLEA.MONTH = VALUES(SS.month), 
  TABLEA.COSTCENTRE = VALUES(SS.SOURCE), 
  TABLEA.AMOUNT = VALUES(SS.TOTALAMOUNT)
;
```

So the answer I am looking for, is:

1. I want **TABLEA** to have a line for each **UNIQUE** that is in the **SELECT** query.
2. If TABLEA contains the same **UNIQUEID** as the **SELECT**, then I want it to update the **YEAR**, **MONTH**, **COSTCENTRE**, **AMOUNT** from the SELECT query

Comment: I believe that it should be `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE YEAR = VALUES(YEAR)` - i.e. you should refer to the column names of TABLEA only

Comment: Hi Ivo. Brilliant.. it worked.

Comment: Great. I will convert the comment as answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converted my comment to an answer.

I believe that it should be `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE YEAR = VALUES(YEAR)` - i.e. you should refer to the column names of TABLEA only